# sum of all previous rows in grouped data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

In a grouped data.frame, I want to add a new column that sums up all previous values from another column.

Here is an example data.frame:

```
grouped_distances <- data.frame (
        group = c (rep ("A", 4), rep ("B", 2), rep ("C", 6)),
        day = c (1:4, 1:2, 1:6),
        distance = c (seq (0,6.5, length.out = 4), 
                   0, 3.6, 
                   0, (rnorm (5, mean = 3))^2) %>% round (digits = 1)
        )




> grouped_distances
   group day distance
1      A   1      0.0
2      A   2      2.2
3      A   3      4.3
4      A   4      6.5
5      B   1      0.0
6      B   2      3.6
7      C   1      0.0
8      C   2     14.5
9      C   3     21.6
10     C   4      1.9
11     C   5      5.9
12     C   6     11.1
```

I want to add the column "total_path" that sums up all distances covered in the previous days for each group. The result would be:

```
   group day distance total_path
1      A   1      0.0        0.0
2      A   2      2.2        2.2
3      A   3      4.3        6.5
4      A   4      6.5       13.0
5      B   1      0.0        0.0
6      B   2      3.6        3.6
7      C   1      0.0        0.0
8      C   2     13.7       14.5
9      C   3     13.6       36.1
10     C   4      4.8       38.0
11     C   5      8.6       43.9
12     C   6     13.9       55.0
```

I tried something such as

```
grouped_distances %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
      total_path = sum (distance) ,
  ) %>% 
    dplyr::ungroup ()
```

which, of course, gives me

```
   group   day distance total_path
   <chr> <int>    <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 A         1      0         13  
 2 A         2      2.2       13  
 3 A         3      4.3       13  
 4 A         4      6.5       13  
 5 B         1      0         3.6
 6 B         2      3.6       3.6
 7 C         1      0         55  
 8 C         2     14.5       55  
 9 C         3     21.6       55  
10 C         4      1.9       55  
11 C         5      5.9       55  
12 C         6     11.1       55
```

Then I tried to use `dplyr::lag ()` (`total_path = dist + lag (distance)`)in order to avoid using all values, but only succeded to calculate the sum of two consecutive days. I also tried `total_path = sum (lag (distance [1:dplyr::row_number()])` but without success. Perhaps someone can help...

This question is similar to
[R: Subtract rows from the first row in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72534996/r-subtract-rows-from-the-first-row-in-each-group)
however, there is a notable difference: I need to sum up all previous values in a group compared to calculating new values "only" from the actual an the previous row.

Comment: try ```cumsum``` instead of ```sum```

Comment: The magic of cumsum! Try `grouped_distances |> 
  dplyr::mutate(total_path = cumsum(distance), .by = group)`

Comment: FYI, when asking a question where you randomly generate values (e.g., `rnorm`) it is helpful if you set a seed (e.g., `set.seed(1)`) so that your exact example data can be reproduced.

Comment: Related (likely a dupe, one of many): https://stackoverflow.com/q/47192687/3358272

Comment: cumsum did the trick. thank you. sometimes, it is really straightforward... however, you need to know the right functions. thank you!

Comment: (It's _always_ easier when you know the answer ;-)